# Using inheritance to define nxn matrices

Tags: java, inheritance, processing

I have already written a class for nxn matrices (I've written this in processing, but I hope that the idea is still clear)

```
class Matrix {
  float[][] entries;

  Matrix(int n_) {

    n = n_;
    entries = new float[n][n];
  }

  float[][] getEntries() {
    return entries;
  }

  void setEntries(float[][] k) {
    entries = k;
  }
}
```

but would like now to generalize for nxm matrices, but wants to keep the code for things already written for nxn matrices, without altering it, I had the idea of writing a new class Gmatrix:

```
class Gmatrix {
  float[][] entries;
  int row;
  int col;

  Gmatrix(int row_, int col_) {
    row = row_;
    col = col_;
    entries = new float[row][col];
  }

  float[][] getEntries() {
    return entries;
  }

  void setEntries(float[][] k) {
    //  entries = k;

  }
}
```

but I basically just want to write something like row=n, col=n in the Matrix class, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: In the constructor of `Matrix`: `super(n_, n_);`. Note that you should validate the size of `k` in `setEntries`; and take a defensive copy of it; and return a defensive copy in `getEntries`.

Comment: @AndyTurner but then in code that refers to the class, wouldn't I have to replace Matrix A = new Matrix(5) with Matrix A = new Matrix(5,5) everywhere?

Comment: No. You'd still be passing a single parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a more general type that takes in both arguments. Here's a simpler example:

```
class RectangularMatrix{
  int rows;
  int columns;

  public RectangularMatrix(int rows, int columns){
    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;
  }

  public void printRowsAndColumns(){
    println(rows + ", " + columns);
  }
}
```

Then a more specific type that extends this class and takes in just a single parameter:

```
class SquareMatrix extends RectangularMatrix{
  public SquareMatrix(int length){
    super(length, length);
  }

  public void onlyApplicableToSquareMatrix(){
    // put code specific to SquareMatrix here
  }
}
```

You could then use a `SquareMatrix` anywhere you could previously use a `RectangleMatrix`. Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/inheritance) is a tutorial on inheritance.

But honestly I don't see a ton of value in the more specific type. Just use the general type and pass in the correct arguments.

Comment: most of the code I wrote (determinants etc.) only makes sense for nxn matrices, so I didn't want to go back and start writing "throw" everywhere and updating all the parameters etc.

Comment: @AndresMejia but what about the case where you've got an instance of a rectangular matrix that *happens* to be square? Would you not want to calculate its determinant? Or would you want to force explicit conversion to a square matrix first?

Comment: @AndresMejia Okay, so put that code inside the `SquareMatrix` class then. I've updated my answer to include an example of that.